# How can I unit test the request response cycle in Node.js?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, httprequest

For example suppose I have the following

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ip;
    if(req.headers['x-forwarded-for']){
        ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    }
    else {
        ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    }
});
```

I would like to unit test to see whether ip is being properly retrieved.  One way is as follows

```
function getIp(req) {
    var ip;
    if(req.headers['x-forwarded-for']){
        ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    }
    else {
        ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
    }
    return ip;
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var ip = getIp(req);
});
```

Now I have a function getIp that I can unit test.  However I'm still stuck.  How can I feed a simulated req object into getIp?

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just write [integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing)-tests for that. Node.js is fast enough for that. Especially when you use something like [Mocha's](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) watch-mode. You could use something like [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or request to perform http requests.

There is also something like for example [nock](https://github.com/flatiron/nock) to [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) out your http requests. Although I have never used it because integration-tests test the real thing and are fast enough for my tast.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha) to write your unit tests in which case you'll use 'request' as your http client. But the simplest way to get started is to use the following:

```
var http = require('http');
//Change to the ip:port of your server
var client = http.createClient(3000, 'localhost'); 

var request = client.request('GET', '/',
  {'host': 'localhost'});
request.end();
request.on('response', function (response) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(response.headers));
  response.setEncoding('utf8');
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```